# Php form with radio value and queries message

Tags: php, html, radio-button

```js
<!-- PHP CONTACT FORM -->
<?php
$look = $_POST['look'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$old_website = $_POST['old_website'];
$redesign = $_POST['redesign'];
?>


    <?php
$field_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['user_message'];

$mail_to = 'alzirabarretto@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Queries';

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Thank you for the message.');
  window.location = '/website_form.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to alzirabarretto@gmail.com');
  window.location = '/website_form.html';
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I update the php code. When sending the mail it works fine but i don't understand when I didn't received my mail. I have change the radio value according what you have said. And what about the url which I create the input type? I'm bit little confused how to do in php code.

Comment: Hi Alzira to answer your question i need to clarify something, do you testing this on server or your localhost?  Thanks

Comment: test on server. to clarify I'm not very good in explaining but I will try to explain here. The previous code which I have in my portfolio contact (php only mail code) is working and I got mail in my inbox. I have copy the same code in another page and edit it the radio value. It works but didn't received my mail when I send it.

Comment: please don't use [tag:radio] for questions about the radio button user interface element; use [tag:radio-button] instead. [tag:radio] is about wireless transmissions.

Comment: Is this question has been solve? If not i will try post the answer.

Comment: Yes @FiidoFirdauz it has been solved thanks for asking...

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong.

```
$radio = $_POST['look' , 'design', 'old_website' , 'redesign'];
```

Try capturing them separately like this,

```
$look = $_POST['look'];
$design = $_POST['design'];
$old_website = $_POST['old_website'];
$redesign = $_POST['redesign'];
```

And even for radio group `LOOK`, try changing the corresponding values. Or you will get value as `radio_1`,`radio_2`, ...